# Do you hate hats?

Tags: discussion

It's that time of year again - WinterBash.

This event will run from **14 December 2015** to **3 January 2016**. Individual users who don’t want to participate, don’t want to see hats, and/or are generally anti-hat will have an “I hate hats” option available. The only visual change to the Stack Exchange sites themselves will be the presence of the hats and the “I hate hats” button in the footer.

We have until December 10 to decide. If we do not make a decision by then, we are opt'd IN by default.

Does CommunityBuilding.SE want to gather hats again this winter?

<sub>Personal aside: Even though I copied a lot of text for this post, AJ isn't allowed to copy his answer from last year. Sorry. Only one copy/paste per meta post and I claimed it :)</sub>

Comment: What is the event in question?

Comment: [Winter Bash 2015](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 7):

## We *hat*'ve to do hats!

We aren't as formal as some other communities, and it seemed to go over well last year. Hats would be beneficial* and a good thing to bond over!

<sub>*Which really means super fun</sub>